# Does every differentiable a.e. function admit a maximally differentiable representative?

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

For $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a measurable function, we say $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a *modification* of $f$ if $f = g$ a.e.

Suppose $f$ Is a measurable function that is differentiable a.e.

We say that a modification $g$ of $f$ is *maximally differentiable* if whenever $h$ is another modification of $f$, we have that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, if $h$ is differentiable at $x$, then so is $g$.

**Question:** Does every measurable, differentiable a.e. function $f$ admit a modification that is maximally differentiable?

Comment: It seems like Zorn's lemma should be able to give this to you.

Comment: Do you know the answer if “differentiable” is replaced by “continuous” throughout? Because it seems to me that this should be answered first.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I believe the answer for the continuous case is to take the “Lebesgue representative”, that is, $g(x) := \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{B_r (x)} f(y) dy$ if the limit exists, $g(x) = f(x)$ otherwise.

Comment: To see that this works, note that if $h$ is another representative of $f$, wherever the limit exists, the definition of $g$ works just as well with $h$ in place of $f$, and then $g$ is clearly continuous whenever $h$ is.

Comment: Hmm perhaps $g$ must be defined slightly differently - it should be between the limsup and liminf of that expression whenever the limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: Hm I believe actually the same construction works for the differentiable case!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator*\appliminf{app-liminf}\DeclareMathOperator*\applimsup{app-limsup}\DeclareMathOperator*\applim{app-lim}\DeclareMathOperator*\essliminf{ess liminf}\DeclareMathOperator*\esslimsup{ess limsup}$The answer is indeed yes. Further, the assumption that $f$ be differentiable a.e. is unnecessary. The main idea for this solution was suggested by Sam Forster on another website.

Define the function $g$ by

$$g(x) := \frac{1}{2} \bigl (\appliminf_{y \to x} f(y) + \applimsup_{y \to x} f(y) \bigr),$$

whenever the above two limits are finite, and $g(x) = f(x)$ otherwise, where here $\appliminf$ and $\applimsup$ denote the [approximate limit supremum and limit infimum](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Approximate_limit).

We note that $g$ has the following properties:

1. $g(x) = \applim_{y \to x} f(y)$ wherever the limit exists. In particular the limit exists wherever $f$ is differentiable and equals $f(x)$.
2. $g$ depends only on the equivalence class of $f$ modulo null sets.

Now I claim that this $g$ is maximally differentiable. To see this, let $h$ be another representative of $f$ and assume $h$ is differentiable at $x$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, and $L \in \mathbb R$ such that

$$\left\lvert\frac{h(y) - h(x)}{y - x} - L\right\rvert \leq \varepsilon$$

whenever $\lvert y-x\rvert < \delta$.

I claim that the same holds for $g$, thus $g$ is differentiable as well at $x$. To see this, note that by (2) above, we may write

$$g(x) := \frac{1}{2} \bigl (\appliminf_{y \to x} h(y) + \applimsup_{y \to x} h(y)\bigr ).$$

Next, we note that for all $y$ with $\lvert y - x\rvert < \delta$,

$$\frac{\essliminf_{z \to y} h(z) - h(x)}{y - x} \leq \frac{g(y) - g(x)}{y - x} \leq \frac{\esslimsup_{z \to y} h(z) - h(x)}{y - x}$$

where we have applied (1) to write $g(x) = h(x)$. This implies

\begin{gather*}
\frac{(L - \varepsilon)(y-x)}{y - x} \leq \frac{g(y) - g(x)}{y - x} \leq \frac{(L + \varepsilon)(y -x)}{y - x} \\
L -\varepsilon \leq \frac{g(y) - g(x)}{y - x} \leq L + \varepsilon.
\end{gather*}

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\lim_{y \to x} \frac{g(y) - g(x)}{y - x} = L$ and so $g$ is differentiable at $x$ as claimed.

Comment: Didn't have the time to read fully (so far), but what about when the approximate lim sup and lim inf are infinite: does this require a tweak?

Comment: Hey John, thanks for writing up my suggestion and fixing the gap. As @Gro-Tsen pointed out, there is an issue with infinite limits. However we can tweak this by defining $g(x) := f(x)$ whenever at least one of the two limits is infinite. I think this should work, but I haven’t checked the details.

Comment: Yes, this should still work since whenever it matters those limits are finite.